# How to get user details from spring security 3.1 and active directory by LDAP

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

I'm new in Java and Java EE. Can you tell me how to retrive user details like full name, company, phone, department, mail, etc. from Active Directore after successful login, so:

my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
                 /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

my applictionContextsecurity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- LDAP server details --> 
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="org.mops.security.ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper"/>

<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="xxx.local" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://xxx.local:389/" /> 
    <beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/**">
    <!-- Login pages -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/user/" 
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/"/>

    <!-- Security zones -->
    <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/it/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATION" /> -->
</security:http>
```

I can login properly, i can get username in controler:

UserController.java:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class UserController{
private String username;
@RequestMapping("/user")
public String User(Model model) {

    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
      this.username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
    } else {
      this.username = principal.toString();
    }
    model.addAttribute("message", username);

    return "user";
 }


}
```

And now I think about creating class, that stores all of user details and create the instance of this class when i need to use user details.

Anyone can tell me step by step how to do this?

Comment: If all you are wanting is the Principal, you can simply include `Principal principal` as one of the arguments to your handler method and Spring will fill it in for you. See the section titles "Supported handler method arguments and return types" here:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Comment: Ok, but how i can get departmen, etc.?

Comment: You need to cast the Principal to whatever object your are expecting.  Otherwise, you don't see the properties on the object.

Answer (score 4):

After two weeks, I found solution.

In pring-security.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider" >
    <beans:constructor-arg value="xxx.yyy" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://zzz.xxx.yyy:389/" /> 
    <beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper" />
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And in controller we cast Principal to InetOrgPerson:

```
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPerson;


@Controller
public class UserController  {
private String username;


@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String User(Model model) throws NamingException {
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();


    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
      this.username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();

    } else {
      this.username = principal.toString();

    }
        model.addAttribute("username", username);        
        model.addAttribute("roomNumber", ((InetOrgPerson) principal).getRoomNumber());
    return "user";
}

}
```

Comment: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPerson